# How to replace default hamburger icon with custom drawable (Used latest NavigationView, design support library, tool bar))

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop, android-navigationview

I have followed exact steps in the following tutorial for making navigation drawer using design support library. But i want to replace the default hamburger icon (using `drawerToggle.syncState()`). How can i do it?

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Also I want to make Navigation drawer switch activities instead of fragments. For this, i have made a `BaseActivity` following above tutorial and extended all other activities from this `BaseActivity`. I am able to get the result but when a new activity is launched unable to preserve the highlighting of selected item in navigation drawer. Please suggest any solutions?